# Scrolling a UIScrollView from outside of that area?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

To have paging work in a UIScrollView and to have it stop where you want, each stop must be a multiple of the scrollview size, and using `clipsToBounds` you can make the UIScrollView image appear outside of the scroll view. This means my scrollview is only 55 pixels wide, but the image inside appears across the whole view. However, I want the user to be able to drag outside the scroll view, where they're seeing the image, and have this touch event have an effect on the scroll view.

Suggestions on how I could get this to work?

Comment: Why don't you amplify the size of the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to implement your own version of paging, in which you use a scroll view delegate to detect when scrolling has ended, and then manually set the scroll view's content offset in an animated way.  I've done this before, and it's not that hard.  Really, the crux of the problem is that you are attempting to use paging for something that isn't technically paging.  You just want it to scroll in discrete amounts.